# Insert row into datagridview using particular columns

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have form that I want to add a row inside a `datagridview`.

I am using the following code

```
Form1.datagridview.rows.add( New string() {Value1, value2, value3, value4, value5})
```

How do I change this so I can target a particular column without having to count them?

Comment: Clarify a little more, if your adding a row you'll have items for each column, but you want to target a specific column?

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the column name instead of

```
datagridview.rows(rownumber).cells("column name").value = "Any Thing"
```